# Do iOS 7 iCloud apps need to be Updated for iCloud Drive?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, ios8

I have an app that uses iCloud to store a Core Data database of a moderately sized amount of data. I realized that on my test iCloud account, when I converted to iCloud Drive, all the data was wiped out.

I added more sample data, but with the simulator as the second device, I cannot determine if the data is properly syncing between devices.

These may be a consequence of iOS 8 still in beta, but I still have the question:

**Do I need to change the way I do my iCloud syncing for iOS 8?**

For more information, I am currently using [iCloudCoreDataStack](https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack) in the app. The app only uses iCloud for Core Data, no documents or key value stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded my phone to iOS 8 GM yesterday, and there was an option to enable iCloud Drive, with the warning that other devices without the same option won't sync anymore. So I did, and my app's iCloud data is still retrieved.

So my guess is now Apple provides migration from old iCloud to the new iCloud Drive, which is a one-way operation. The previous iCloud data won't get lost (otherwise it'd be a disaster for lots of iOS apps), but wouldn't sync to old iCloud devices anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So I and many-many other developers have the issue with migration their iCloud databases from iOS 7 to iOS 8 with missing the data. But you have no need to upgrade your application, but there are many troubles with migration.

Answer (score 0):

My app saves NSData to iCloud Documents. But upon updating to iCloud Drive, the data is NOT retrievable and new data files are not being saved to iCloud Drive either.

It is a dog's dinner of a transition by Apple, with documentation for users and developers currently being very poor indeed.